# All the options under ribbon tabs are greyed out in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ribbon-control

All the options under ribbon tabs are greyed out in SharePoint 2013. I am only the site administrator and site owner and permissions has been set to full control but still all the options are disabled under ribbon tabs i.e in format text and insert ribbon tab.

Even I selected the web part and checked but still the options are greyed out. I have to modify content editor web part but I am not able to do that.

[image: First error ribbon]

[image: Second error ribbon]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that no one else has the page already checked out / editing?

You can choose Site Actions > Show ribbon.

If another user has it checked out, sometimes this can happen - looks like your permissions have been lost, when in fact the page is being edited by another user.